# Operations between Subsequences' proof

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty bounded subset of $R$

a)  If $C={x+y:x∈A,y∈B}$, prove that $C$ is bounded above and that $\sup ⁡C=\sup⁡ A+\sup ⁡B$.

b)
    If$ D={x-y:x∈A,y∈B}$, prove that $D$ is bounded above and that $\sup ⁡D=\sup ⁡A-\inf⁡ B$.

c)
    If $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, $\alpha>0$, then $\sup⁡\{\alpha x:x\in A\}=\alpha \sup ⁡A$.

I know that since $A$ and $B$ are bounded and $C$ or $D$ is the sum/ difference of sub-sequence of $A$ and $B$ so $C$, $D$ must be bounded. So they must bounded above. But I don't know know to prove it formally.

Comment: Well, take $x\in A,y\in B$. Can you explain why $x+y\leq \sup A+\sup B$? If so, all that remains is to find $x_n,y_n$ such that $x_n+y_n = \sup A+\sup B$ (and similarly for the other cases)

Comment: because $ x∈A,y∈B$, $x,y$ can be accummulation points of $A$ and $B$, thus $x ≤ sup A$ and $y ≤ sup b$, which lead to $x+y≤supA+supB$ Is that correct? I always have problem writing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a)

For my own sake let me call  $a:=supA$ and $b:=supB$.

First we need to show that the set $C:=\{\, x+y: x\in A \text{ and } y \in B \}$ is non-empty and bounded above. Clearly is non empty, since exists at least one $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ by hypothesis and then $x+y\in C$. Now we need to show that C is bounded above, by the properties of the LUB we know that, $x\le a$ for all the $x\in A$ and similarly $y\le b$ for all $y\in B$. Let $x$ and $y$ be arbitrary so $\,x+y\le a+b$ and since $x$ and $y$ were arbitrary it follows that for each arbitrary element the inequality holds, which means that $a+b$ is an upper bound for $C$ as desired.

Thus, since $C$ is non empty and bounded above has a least upper bound. Let $c= sup C$. Since $a+b$ is an upper bound it follows that $c \le a+b$. To conclude the proof we need to show that $a+b\le c$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Then there is a $x\in A$ such that  $x >a-\epsilon/2 $  (if were not, implies $a-\epsilon/2$ is an upper bound contradicting that $a$ is the LUB of $A$) and a $y\in B$ such that $y >b-\epsilon/2 $ (for a similar argument) and then $x+y> a+b-\epsilon$ for each arbitrary $\epsilon$. Furthermore $c\ge x+y> a+b-\epsilon$, so $\, a+b\le c+\epsilon$.

> Claim 1: If $\, u\le v+\epsilon\,$ for each $\epsilon>0$. Then $u\le v$

Proof of claim 1: We may assume by contradiction $\,v < u$. Let $\epsilon = (u-v)/2$ (which clearly is a positive number). Then we have:

$v+\epsilon = \frac{u+v}{2} <\frac{(u+u)}{2}=u$, i.e., $\,v+\epsilon<u$, a contradiction. Therefore, $u\le v$.

Thus $\, a+b\le c+\epsilon\,$ for each $\epsilon$ so, by the claim 1, $a+b\le c$, as desired. Hence $a+b = c$, i.e., $supA+supB=supC$.

The other part (b) and (c) are quite similar.